# why is the set width not working properly in c++ for me

Tags: c++

On line 68 I have the set width set to change accordingly to the width of the name if the name has 6 letter it will show 9 space for it. I cant seem to get it to act properly it sets the width differently for different names.

Here is how it currently prints

```
Name     Quiz ScoreProject ScoreTest Score  TotalGrade
food       25.00  30.00  89.00 144.00 C
imfreakingawesome  22.00  30.00  79.00 131.00 D
thisiscool  22.00  30.00  89.00 141.00 C
eatfood    22.00  30.00  99.00 151.00 C
codeit     22.00  29.00  99.00 150.00 C
```

This is how I need it to print

```
Name              Quiz ScoreProject ScoreTest Score  TotalGrade<--disregard line
food              25.00  30.00  89.00 144.00 C
imfreakingawesome  22.00  30.00  79.00 131.00 D
thisiscool        22.00  30.00  89.00 141.00 C
eatfood           22.00  30.00  99.00 151.00 C
codeit            22.00  29.00  99.00 150.00 C
```

There are stars next to the lines where i set it

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
void calculateTotal (double qS[], double pS[], double tS[], double total[], int SIZE);
void calculateGrade (double total[], double grade[], int SIZE);
void generateReport (string names[], double qS[], double pS[], double tS[], double total[], char grade[], int SIZE);

double totalScore[5];
char finalGrade[5];
int nameWidth;

int main()
{

    string studentName[5];
    double quizScore[5];
    double projectScore[5];
    double testScore[5];
    double grade[5]; //dont understand the need for this
    double total[5];
    int lastwidth=0;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter student's name"<<endl;
        cin>>studentName[i];

        cout<<"Enter student's quiz score"<<endl;
        cin>>quizScore[i];
        while(quizScore[i]>25||quizScore[i]<0)
        {
            cout<<"Enter a quiz score between 0 and 25"<<endl;
            cin>>quizScore[i];
        }

        cout<<"Enter student's project score"<<endl;
        cin>>projectScore[i];
        while(projectScore[i]>30||projectScore[i]<0)
        {
            cout<<"Enter a project score between 0 and 30"<<endl;
            cin>>projectScore[i];
        }

        cout<<"Enter student's test score"<<endl;
        cin>>testScore[i];
        while(testScore[i]>100||testScore[i]<0)
        {
            cout<<"Enter a test score between 0 and 100"<<endl;
            cin>>testScore[i];
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        calculateTotal(quizScore, projectScore,testScore,total,i);

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        calculateGrade (totalScore, grade,i);

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)        
        if(studentName[i].length()+3>lastwidth)
            nameWidth=(studentName[i].length()+3);

    // The problem lies here    
    cout<<left<<setw(nameWidth)<<"Name"<<setw(7)<<right<<fixed<<"Quiz Score"<<setw(7)<<right<<"Project Score"<<setw(7)<<right<<"Test Score"<<setw(7)<<right<<"Total"<<setw(5)<<right<<"Grade"<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    generateReport(studentName,quizScore,projectScore,testScore,totalScore,finalGrade,i);                                   
}

// And here lies the problem, too
void generateReport (string names[], double qS[], double pS[], double tS[], double total[], char grade[], int SIZE)
{ //width of 7 is better
    cout<<left<<setw(nameWidth)<<names[SIZE]<<setw(7)<<right<<fixed <<setprecision(2)<<qS[SIZE]<<setw(7)<<right<<pS[SIZE]<<setw(7)<<right<<tS[SIZE]<<setw(7)<<right<<total[SIZE]<<setw(2)<<right<<grade[SIZE]<<endl;
}

void calculateTotal (double qS[], double pS[], double tS[], double total[], int SIZE)
{
    totalScore[SIZE]=qS[SIZE]+pS[SIZE]+tS[SIZE];
}

void calculateGrade (double total[], double grade[], int SIZE)
{
    grade[SIZE]=total[SIZE]/200;
    if (grade[SIZE] >=.90)
        finalGrade[SIZE]='A';
    else if(grade[SIZE] >=.80)
        finalGrade[SIZE]='B';
    else if(grade[SIZE] >=.70)
        finalGrade[SIZE]='C';       
    else if(grade[SIZE] >=.60)
        finalGrade[SIZE]='D';
    else if(grade[SIZE] <=.60)      
        finalGrade[SIZE]='F';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int nameWidth;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (studentName[i].length() + 3 > lastwidth)
    {
        nameWidth = (studentName[i].length() + 3);
    }
}
```

You're checking if the length of the current name is longer than the `lastwidth` and if so you update `nameWidth` but you're not updating `lastWidth` (which is always zero).

This effectively leaves you with the length of the last name in the list plus three.

Why not the following?

```
// Remove the lastwidth variable completely
std::size_t maxNameSize = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    maxNameSize = std::max(maxNameSize, studentName[i].size() + 3);
}
```

**Note:** since this is C++ I'd avoid the C-style arrays and use standard containers (e.g., `std::vector<std::string>` instead of `std::string var[5]`).